# Kali linux network error

Tags: networking, kali-linux

I'm new here and I'm from Tunisia so my English is my 3rd language so forgive me for my bad grammar mistakes.

OK, I have Kali 2.0 linux (32bit) installed in windows 8.1 (32bit) (dual boot, no VM), and have some problems:

After I start apache2 server, I can't reach my local IP server from a other machine even when I scan my network with `nmap` with this command:

```
nmap -sP 192.168.1.1/24
```

But that's not working, and this is scan result:

```
Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2016-03-31 13:41 CET
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.1
Host is up (0.0031s latency).
MAC Address: 80:71:7A:64:F8:34 (Huawei Technologies)
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.100
Host is up.
Nmap done: 256 IP addresses (2 hosts up) scanned in 28.14 seconds`
```

And I'm sure that my phone and my PC are connected to the same wifi.

Also `metasploit` listener is not working it just stay waiting for response, and I'm sure that I have ran `msfvenom` app in my phone.

I tried pinging my PC and it works.

(this question is for learning purpose only)

Comment: What is the question exactly? You found 2 hosts in your scan

Comment: no namp does not detect my phone and my PC and apache2 server not working in other machines and metasploit listeners won't work too : so need some to help because that i think that the router is the problem

Comment: did you try to connect to your page from the local machine either with http://127.0.0.1 or http://localhost? does this show your page if not then the problem is your apache or your website it self. if yes then try to a ifconfig on the local machine to find out your dhcp ip and then make a ping from the other host/phone to that ip to check if your machine is reachable if it is not make a traceroute to find out at which point in the network the communication gets lost.

Answer (score 0):

According to [nmap_osdetect](https://nmap.org/book/osdetect-usage.html) you can use the following command:

```
nmap -sV -O -v 192.168.1.1/24
```